# Reset incrementing value upon received event

Tags: java

I'm supposed to have a value increment from 0. The condition is that whenever it receives `N` event, it will turn back to 0.

I have `count` which has an initial value of 0, when `triggerEvent()` is invoked, it will go back to 0

```
int count = 0;

void triggerEvent() {
    reset();
}

void reset() {
    count=0;
}
```

`count` is incremented whenever the object is initialized. I initially tried to increment it inside a `Runnable`

```
boolean on = true;

Runnable runnable = -> {
    while(on) {
        count++;
    }
}

Constructor() {
    runnable.run();
}

void turnOff() {
    on = false;
}
```

However, I now realize that this is not possible as you cannot use non-final variables inside a lambda.

Does anyone have any other ideas on how I can achieve this?

Edit: Clarification

I need to detect when an `event a` is "idle" for too long (e.g. 30 seconds)

My plans was that I create a class in which it has some sort of timer running in the background. Whenever the `event a` is invoked, the timer is reset back to 0. I have a scheduled service that checks for the value of the timer every `x` seconds. If the timer reaches `30` (supposedly 30 seconds), then a new event is invoked.

Problem is, I'm having a hard time creating the process of a background timer that can be reset upon an event.

Comment: Just replace lambda with private method call and do what you want

Comment: I need the incrementation of `count` to run in the background - in which I realized that putting a while loop inside a `Runnable` won't exactly be what I need.

Comment: Remove your infinite loop..

Comment: Actually, what is it exactly you want to do here? Simply increase the count when some object in created? In that case, you don't need an infinite loop. Must it be done with only lambda expression? Why do you need a thread for that?

Comment: No. Hold on I'll try to explain it more clearly.